# Android & iOS user authentication

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I am about to create an application for Android and iOS that requires the user to create an account. 
Since the app will need a server to store user information and authenticate the user I was thinking about using the App Engine from Google but it seems like it doesn't support iOS language(Objective-C). 
Do you now any similar services that will work for both Android and iOS?

It will have to be able to store user credentials/authenticate the user and store strings and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a backend, right?

If I got the question, you can use the App Engine, it support any front end you want to, here is a sample of using it with and iOS app.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_ios